# How to printf align my output like a table?

Tags: shell, sh

How do I printf align my output like a table?

```
Title                                             Author
BaokyBook                                              Baoky2
Use basename commandUse basename command ..             Baoky
```

My partial code is like this

```
titlelength=${#title};
```

First I get the title length, then I printf like this

```
titlespace=`expr 60 - titlelength`;
printf "%s %${titlespace}s\n" "$title" "$author"
```

But the alignment is not right, how do I get it working well aligned

In reply to the answer below:

after making the changes

all my left align to the right. and it doesn't seems working.

Comment: To get left alignment, put a dash (`-`) before the format:  e.g. below answer becomes `printf "%-30s %s\n" "$title" "$author"`.  Note the `-` in `%-30s`.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing would be to print the title on a fixed width:

```
printf "%30s %s\n" "$title" "$author"
```

If you want to determine the max width, you would need to read all of the data before doing any output.  or you could simply pipe your output to `column -t`.  Or, truncate the title to the chosen width (this technique of truncating the string is a bashism):

```
 printf "%30s %s\n" "${title:0:30}" "$author"
```

Comment: the truncated version give  "Bad substitution" on /bin/sh.

Comment: The syntax `${a:0:30}` is a bashism and will not work in most other shells.  `Bad substitution` would indicate the shell is not `bash`.

Comment: Strings can be truncated with `printf` using the precision specifier: `printf '%30.29s $s' "$title" "$author"`